# GCP AutoML Tables: Training Error about "Minimum Valid Row Ratio"

Tags: training-data, automl

I have a single CSV of time series financial data with about 28k rows, and 40 columns. I have set a time column, and set a target column. When I try to train I get "Requires the minimum valid row ratio reaches 0.50 to train a model, while got ratio 0.045313". I have no idea what this means, and theres no documentation. I've tried eliminating columns from the training set but I keep getting the same error.

I've reduced the feature columns hoping to find a culprit to no avail.

Comment: Is no one monitoring this?????